# Regex that doesn't match character declarations

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to come up with a regex that will match things like:

```
( ) , ; { } .
```

but not

`'(' ')' ',' ';'`   etc...

but I am really struggling. Here's what I've got:

```
private String symbolMatcher = "[^'][\\\\(\\\\);\\\\{\\\\}\\\\[\\\\]:\\\\+\\\\-\\\\<\\\\>/\\\\*=&%\\\\|\\\\^@#$~][^']";
```

The over all goal is to be able to tokenize these different things using a scanner:

```
scanner = new Scanner(line);
scanner.useDelimiter("(?=[" + symbolMatcher + "])|(?<=[" + symbolMatcher + "])");
```

example input: `',''.'...@'^`

desired tokens: `(',') ('.') (.) (.) (.) (@) (') (^)`

Comment: Your symbolMatcher string resolves to this `[[^'][\\(\\);\\{\\}\\[\\]:\\+\\-\\<\\>/\\*=&%\\|\\^@#$~][^']]` when plugged into 'useDelimeter'. Its a single composite Java class, with much bad stuff. Can't determine the intent from that. If you could expand the explanation at the top, you might get some solutions. I have no idea what the answer you've chosen does, or how it helps ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the expression to see how it works and for an explanation [`\[^'\]+\[\(\),;{}\.\]`](http://regex101.com/r/bJ5hR5) should give you an idea of how to get started!

Comment: What is this `\[^'\]+\[\(\),;{}\.\]` ? I can't acces your link, can you explain what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, this regexp should help:
`('.*?'|.)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex is what you want:

```
(?<!')[...](?!')
```

Replace the `...` with the characters you want to match, e.g.: `(?<!')[(),;{}.<>+\\-:](?!')`

You can find an explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/qE6nV1.